# Word for someone who is a lover of words

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a one word term for someone who is a lover of words? Similar to language enthusiast but only in a single word.

Comment: A monologophile, perhaps? But perhaps it depends on the word.

Comment: As a side note, this is a very poor title for a question. Nobody clicks on such vague things. You will get more visitors and thus more answers if you provide a specific title that actually matches the question.

Comment: It's poor for several reasons, not the least of which being the fact that OP says it refers to someone interested "only in a **single** word." Yet from the OP's comment on the only answer we may assume that that restriction does not, in fact, apply.

Comment: @Robusto But *logophile* ***is*** one word!!! I assume OP uses "in a single word" not to mean interested in a single word, but to mean "language enthusiast but in the form of a single word", surely?

Comment: @Araucaria: Whoa, easy on the exclamation marks. It isn't that big a deal.  For some reason when I read it this morning it looked to me like OP meant what I said. No biggie.

Comment: @Robusto Exclamation marks was tongue-in-cheekness, not righteousness :)

Answer (score 0):

**logophile:** *(n.)* lover of words